# Mixing iAd and Admob for testing ads

Tags: ios, admob, ios-simulator, iad

I've integrated iAds and when i click on an iAd i get the message "Welcome to iAd. You are now connected to world's largest iOS App Network". I haven't signed the App Network agreement yet. Today i also opened up Google's AdMob account and implemented google's test ads. However, on my simulator the iAds don't play at all anymore and only the Google test ads play.  I made Google's ads refresh rate at 30 seconds. I get only Google ads playing and iAd never shows up. How do I change this so both iAd and AdMob show up changing from iAd to Admob?

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to load both ads networks' classes into your app and instantiate them individually (e.g. one banner points to iAd via the iAd SDK, and one points to AdMob via the AdMob SDK)?  If so, consider using mediation.  You can incorporate more networks, adjust targets after deployment, and the whole thing's a lot cleaner.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/mediation

Comment: I've added the Google's AdMob sdk into Xcode project. I've added iAd adapter into Xcode Project. In Google's Admob account i've mediated iAds with higher eCPM than Admob's eCPM. I currently have Admob test banner running on top of the simulator and iAd "You're not connected to iAd" banner on top of screen as well. I haven't signed into iAd network contract yet. However, The Admob Banner always stays on and never changes to iAd banner. Is this because test banners don't get tested in mediation? Do I have to test real banners only on simulator to see iAd AdMob mediation work?